# Scheme/Racket: Expected a variable, but found a number error

Tags: scheme, racket

I have defined a function `name` in the form 
`(define (name x y z) (function...))`

I call `name` with the parameters `int1` `int2` `int3` on a new line like this
`(define (name int1 int2 int3))`

and for some reason, I get the error message:
`define: expected a variable, but found a number.`

I am new to the language(Racket/Scheme) so I am wondering what made Dr.Racket expect a variable? I have used this exact form many times with integers and had no problem with it.

Comment: Please include the code that gives the error, `(define (name int1 int2 int3))` is another error: a function declaration with no function body.

Comment: Please include which language you are using in addition to the code that gives this error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to define a function and how to use it after the definition.

```
(define (add-them x y z)  ; note x, y, and, z must me names
  (+ x y z))

(add-them 1 2 3)          ; no  define  when add-them is used.
```

The result is 6.

Answer (score 0):

A bare symbol in code,  like `i`,  `cons`,  and `+`,  are variables. They evaluate to values. For `+`,  when not shadowed by a lexical binding, would evaluate to the  procedure for addition.

`(+ a b)` is code with 3 variables. Variable  `+` needs to evaluate to a procedure and `a` and `b` needs to evaluate to types that `#<procedure:+>` expects.

If you have put the parentheses as in C, `+(1 2)`,  then that is two expressions. First `+` that evaluates to a procedure,  but the value is not used, and the next expression  `(1 2)` which is clearly an error since `1` is not  a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a post from a month ago, here is what I believe is an answer.
First you've defined your function `name`:

```
(define (name x y z) (function...))
```

Now you've tried to call `name`:

```
(define (name int1 int2 int3))
```

what happens here is that racket sees `define` first and thinks that you are defining something. This could be a function or a variable. (They have their similarities in racket.) Then it moves on to `(name int1 int2 int3)`. Note that this is a function call and it does whatever you have defined above. In this case, I assume you have defined your function `name` to return a number. So now we are looking at `(define some_number)`. What does this mean? Racket isn't too sure, because it was expecting a variable name.
Either one of the two below should work:

```
(define some_number (name int1 in2 int3)) //It defines `some_number` as whatever the result of the function call is.
(name int1 int2 int3) // simply calls the function with the arguments int1 int2 int3
```